# Powershell Script to compare VolumeID to DriveLetter

Tags: powershell, volumes, drive-letter

I have a powershell script running wbadmin with source C: to a target iSCSI volume which is specified by its volume ID (\?\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}).
The backup itself runs perfectly fine, I just wanted to add an offsite-backup functionality to the script. Sadly, robocopy cannot use the Volume ID as source for the copy job and will reject it as unknown parameter.

Is there a way to conveniently get the actual drive letter from the volume ID so i can replace it before calling robocopy?

The output of "mountvol" looks very promising, but if there is a powershell integrated feature, I would preferably use it.

I already tried Get-PSDrive and Get-Volume, there seems to be no way of getting them to output the VolumeID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe this should help:

```
gwmi Win32_Volume |
    ? { $_.deviceID -eq '\?\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\'} 
          | select -expand name
```

Comment: I upvote only because I assume it's going to work. Haven't actually tested it but I'm pretty sure I've had to do something like this in the past.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Didn't think of accessing WMI directly. I would upvote it too, but i still need some rep :(

Comment: @HannesS Glad to help! No prob for the upvote I'm here just for fun ;)